# create pandas.DataFrame from Postgreql and convert multiple rows and one column to one row and multiple column

Tags: python, pandas

i have a postgresql db that look like this:

```
price
1
2
4
9
7
8
3
7
5
3
7
```

and I want it to look like this:
1 2 4 9 7 8 3 7 5 3 7

I'm reding it using `pandas.read_sql()`
now I want to convert that the DataFrame will be instead of 11 rows and one column to be 1 row and
11 column, from what I'm understanding I need to use the `pandas.melt()` function but I didn't understand how?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
df.T
Out[7]: 
       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
price   1   2   4   9   7   8   3   7   5   3   7
```

Comment: but it not saving the DataFrame like that it just printing it like this no?